# Login page Not found. Jsp pages not found. Moving from jboss 7.1.1 to wildfly 13

Tags: java, maven, server, jboss

When moving to wildfly 13 the project which is running on spring the server stopped to show jsp pages. Controllers code got executed and everything worked fine but the server responded 404 on the jsp pages rendering.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a week on this issue I found that the reason for this was that in my web.xml I had registered a servlet with name jsp. Jboss registers this servlet by itself to serve jsp pages. But if you have declared it itself it may cause problems. So to solve this if you have jsp servlet registered then try to remove it from web.xml